Does tapasya burn all karmas?
I have heard that tapasya burns all negative past karmas. Is it true? Is there a scriptural reference for it? Does that mean the horoscope will stop working completely as karma has been put to rest?

Burn doesn't mean your Karmic crimes are forgiven. Burnt means, that Karmic results that are due upon your psyche will come and cause its effect. But you in your tapas will be able to both endure it and ignore it and not be wounded by it. As Sadhguru once said about pain (Klesha) , "The question is only, will you get wounded or will you get wise"

Cessation of (spiritual )ignorance ( source of all bondage) is one that burns all past karma  . However it cannot be attained as a direct effect of any mental/physical act .Tapasya being a mental act , is only a stepping stone that aids ablazing past karma ,though it can't be said as a direct means to achive the same. chapter 4 of Bhagavad Gita details the same .

यथैधांसि समिद्धोऽग्निर्भस्मसात्कुरुतेऽर्जुन।
ज्ञानाग्निः सर्वकर्माणि भस्मसात्कुरुते तथा।।4.37।।
O Arjuna, as a blazing fire reduces pieces of wood to ashes, similarly the fire of Knowledge reduces all actions to ashes.

Liberation is not an effect to be attained; it is only to be realized through knowledge, since it is eternally existent. (It is not some thing to be brought into existence by any action, since it is ever present and has only to be realized as such).

___the cessation of ignorance alone is what is known as liberation, like the disappearance of the snake, for instance, from the rope when the wrong notion about its existence has been eradicated.  (Sri Shankara bhashya br. up. 4.4.6)

Sri Shankaracharyas commentary Brahma Sutra 1.1.4

__nanu jnaanam naama maanasii kriyaa. na, vailakshaNyaat-------- veditavyam.____
jnaanam (knowledge) is not a mental act, because there is a difference (between knowledge and meditation). A mental act is seen to exist where there is an injunction about it, which is independent of the nature of the thing concerned. dhyaanam (meditation), is a mental act, because it depends on the will of the person performing it. For example, to think of a man or woman as fire, as enjoined in  O Gautama, man is surely fire (Ch.up.5.7.1) , or in O Gautama, woman is surely fire(Ch.up.5.8.1) is certainly a mental act, since it arises from an injunction alone. But the idea of fire with regard to the well-known fire is not dependent on any injunction or on the will of any man. (In other words, thinking of one thing as another, like a linga as Lord Siva and worshipping it as such, is meditation and it is a mental act, because it depends on the will of the worshipper. But looking at an ordinary stone and seeing it as a stone is knowledge and is not a mental act, because it does not depend on the will of the person). While meditation depends on the will of a person, knowledge depends only on the object concerned and on valid means of knowledge, such as perception. Meditation is therefore described as purusha-tantra (dependent on the person), while knowledge is called vastu-tantra (dependent on the object to be known).   Translation  Sri SN Saastri

